# What's the point of prefixing each element in the column by its column number in multicolumn GiN indexes?

Tags: postgresql, index

According to [**these slides**](http://www.sigaev.ru/gin/fastinsert_and_multicolumn_GIN.pdf) which, I believe, are incorporated into the current implementation, each column element in multicolumn GiN indexes is prefixed by its column number and is stored separately from one another, so they use storage of Na+Nb instead of Na*Nb for `(a int[], b int[])`. And the following slides show 2.5X speed improvement for a select query over 2 single column indexes.

But where does this huge performance improvement come from? I don't see why they are so much more efficient than 2 single column indexes. If you prefix each element with its column number, at every level in the tree, they'll be completely split into left and right, and left subset have no relation to the right subset just like 2 single column indexes, so I think they should be very similar in performance.

Comment: The slides you refer to date back to 2008 and discuss improvements for the very old version 8.4. There have been several major updates for GIN indexes since. [Version 9.4 was another game changer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/release-9-4.html#AEN119954). As for your question: I did not study the details of the presentation but I'd guess the overhead of combining two bitmap index scans is larger than a single (slightly more expensive) index scan that combines the two values internally.